# Show hidden files for default on Centos via ssh

Tags: centos, ftp, files

I have a VPS Server based on CentOS 6.4 (Final)

The inconvenience: When I log on via SSH (using root user) I can't see hidden files, e.g I can't see (for default) the .httaccess and others system similar files. (also in FTP)

Files exist, because I used `ls -a` and I can see all files, but I think that isn't idea.

Similarly I can't see hidden files on FTP (I use vsFTPd 2.2.2)

Finally, for example my FTP directory has 757 permissions.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a shell alias. For instance in bash:

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

Comment: wow great !
I added the alias in my .bashsrc file, reboot and done! :D
Thanks a lot Michael !

Comment: @joseluisq: It's not necessary to reboot :(

Comment: @lain: It's true :D I rebooted! Logging out was enough :)

Comment: If you add this alias to `~/.bashrc`, the easiest way to enable it is to run: `source ~/.bashrc`.